# Why is this instance member not accessible after instantiation in Python?

Tags: python, class

This variable declared in the contractor does not exist after instantiation? Why?

It worked as expected if declare as a class variable.

```
class Apple():
    def show(self):
        print('apple')


class Basket():
    def __init__(self):
        apple = Apple()


basket = Basket()
basket.apple.show()
```

Output:
AttributeError: 'Basket' object has no attribute 'apple'

```
class Apple():
    def show(self):
        print('apple')


class Basket():
        apple = Apple()


basket = Basket()
basket.apple.show()
```

Output:
apple

This is what I expected.

apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign to an instance variable, you need to assign to `self` like so:

```
class Basket():
    def __init__(self):
        self.apple = Apple()
```

Otherwise, you would just be creating a local variable within the `__init__` function.

Comment: @Round Don't forget to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Round: The main reason you get the `AttributeError` is that in your first definition,
the variable `apple` is just a locale variable.

In order to access it, you must make it effectively an **attribute** of the class,
that's it must be either an **instance variable** or **class variable**.

For example, in the example below:

```
class Apple:
    def show(self):
        print("apple")

class Basket:
    apple = Apple()
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

`apple` is an attribute of the class `Basket`, in particular it is a `class variable`

On the other hand, in the following example:

```
class Apple:
    def show(self):
        print('apple')

class Basket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.apple = Apple()
```

`apple` is still an `attribute` of the class `Basket`, but specifically it is `an instance variable`.

Please, have a look at [Class variable vs. Instance variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) to grasp the difference between
class and instance variables.